# How to access parameters in a method for an array? Java

Tags: java, arrays, variables, methods, parameters

Just trying to understand the basics of how this should work. Here is my code.---------------------------> This is my main class.

```
public class Driver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //create new instance of the ArrayLab class with parameter of 10
        ArrayLab array = new ArrayLab(10);

        //search for 2
        array.search(2);
    }
}
```

The class ArrayLab has a method assigned to it called search with parameter of (2). So far this is what I have.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class ArrayLab
{
    //array instance variable
    int[] array1 = new int[10];

    //array constructor
    public ArrayLab(int integer)
    {
        //class parameter = 10
        int[] array1 = new int[integer];

    }

//method
public void search(int integer)
    {
        int[] array1= new int[]{integer};
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1));
    }
}
```

So the big question is what am I doing right? or wrong? I realize this is probably pretty basic, just struggling to understand what is happening inside the code. Thanks :)

Comment: do you have a error or do you just want to know whats happening?

Comment: Just edited. When I try to print it doesn't return the parameter I set in the search method (2).

Comment: " When I try to print it doesn't return the parameter I set in the search method" , well that's because `search` has a void return type , read up on return types otherwise you'll be stuck on this forever.

Comment: Word of advice: come up with more descriptive names for your variables. Forcing yourself to come up with names that reflect the *meaning* of the variable will help you think through the logic of what you want to achieve. For example, in `public ArrayLab(int integer)`, `integer` would be better named `capacity`, since it determines how many elements the `ArrayLab` can hold. If `search` is actually supposed to access the element at the specified index of the `ArrayLab`, then it would be better named `get(int index)`. `search` suggests you're going to search to see if the `ArrayLab` contains it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Driver` class is good.

So, lets take one line at a time

```
int[] array1 = new int[10];
```

Okay, you made a public int array of size 10, more precisely `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`.

```
public ArrayLab(int integer)
{
    int[] array1 = new int[integer];
}
```

This is called a constructor. You are passing in `integer`, and making a **new** array called `array1` which is local to this scope, therefore different than the one before. This `array1` contains `integer`-many zeros.

To use and initialize the previous `array1`, change your code up to here to this

```
int[] array1;
public ArrayLab(int integer)
{
    this.array1 = new int[integer];
}
```

Next,

```
public void search(int integer)
    {
        int[] array1= new int[]{integer};
    }
}
```

This, again, creates a new array, but only one value. So say `integer` was 2,  then `[2]`.

Comment: This will define the size of the array `[integer]`, He might get confused. Better to put the value itself.

Comment: I should probably change the parameter names to be unique as to not get confused!

Comment: @YoungHobbit - not sure which one you are talking about

Comment: Think he means the parameter inside of search method (2)

Comment: @pewpew - Yes, verbosity and clarity is prefered when learning to code, so `ArrayLab(int size)` and `search(int value)`. Otherwise, Ryan's answer has you covered on `array1`. Use `this.array1` to access the same, initial array.

Comment: I like this answer as well, can i have them both as the answer? :P I like the breaking it down explaining part of it.

Comment: The last line of the answer.

Comment: @YoungHobbit - It doesn't define the size. The size goes in the square braces as before. That line makes an array of size 1, with the only element being the value of `integer`. I updated the answer to specify that.

Comment: I also realized that my instance variable only needs to be "int[] array1;"

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the purpose of your ArrayLab class is , but here are some problems

1. In the constructor you are initializing a local `array1` not your instance variable .
2. `search` method is doing nothing but again initializing a local `array1`.

Comment: Ah ok, so it should be int[] array1= {integer};

Comment: that all depends on what you want to do in your search method .

Comment: Ok interesting, So I'm eventually working on building it into something that can search through an array of #'s and see if it matches the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so whats happening is in your class Driver your creating a object of your class ArrayLab. You send this class a constructor which creates a local variable array1. Your search class initializing another local array1 this is what i would do for your ArrayLab class

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class ArrayLab
{
    int[] array1;

    //array constructor
    public ArrayLab(int integer)
    {
        this.array1 = new int[integer];

    }

//method
public void search(int integer)
    {
        System.out.println(array1[integer]);
    }
}
```

Comment: works perfect, even gets rid of the brackets! Even better :)

Comment: so far all the answers are good information, so hard to pick! :P

Comment: That isn't a search method. It accesses `array1` at position `integer` instead of either returning the index of `integer` or if `array1` contains `integer`.

Comment: ah i thought that we were searching the array by sending a indices that we wanted return, my mistake.